# Web page export as Microsoft word css missing

Tags: html, css

when Export a webpage in Microsoft word in table format the table layout not showing properly missing css styling please help me.

Comment: Save the webpage in a notepad with **.htm** or **.html** format.

Comment: But i'm using webpage as cv format

Comment: Can you just attach any images or show exactly what kind of problem you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

A doc or docx and an html file are very different from each other. If you want to save an offline version of the website, use a scraper or take a screenshot of the webpage you are interested in.

CSS does not work in word and so it is not recognized. There are workarounds but I don't really see the point. Just save the document as an html and work with that! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Goto your Microsoft Word Document.
2. Then goto Insert >> Object >> Text from File
3. Select the required `.html` file from the Insert File Dialog box.
4. Save your document in Word Document (.docx) format.

Or try this one:

1. Save your document as `.html` or `.htm` format.
2. This will create a folder with your documents.
3. Add your `CSS` stylesheet to the created folder. To add **stylesheet**, Goto Developer **Tab** >> Document Template >> Linked CSS >> Add.

Hopefully this will work!